# How to initialize a private variable stack in constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a Class with private variable `stack<int> numbers;`.

How do I initialize it in the constructor?

```
Class::Class() {}
```

I'm familiar with how if I had a private variable int i, I would just do:

```
Class::Class() {
    i = 0; 
}
```

or

```
Class::Class():i(0) {
}
```

but am not sure when it comes to this.

Comment: The same way you do your `int` depending on `stack`'s constructor.

Comment: Please note that your first example (`i = 0;`) is not actually *initialisation,* it's *assignment.* It's pretty much the same for `int`, but with your `std::stack` example, it would be very different indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to default-initialise it, to get an empty stack, then you don't need to do anything. Any member not specified in the initialise list will be default-initialised.

If you like you could be explicit:

```
Class() : numbers() {}
```

but that's entirely optional. If there are no other members or base classes that need explicit initialisation, then you can omit the constructor altogether: the implicitly generated one will do the right thing.

If you need to give it constructor arguments, then do that in the initialiser list:

```
Class() : numbers(args) {}
```

Comment: thank you all. what i was trying to do was create a Class c; and push a number to its numbers stack. then when i tried to get the top value of the stack, i kept getting some random number like 5056176. i thought it was the constructor, but i actually forgot to return an int in my method to get that top value. coming from java, it seems i've discovered with C++ that you can say you're going to return an int in the method declaration, but it'll still compile if you don't!

Comment: @TidusSmith comatibility with C is the reason. But any decent compiler should warn you about this kind of error. You should turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: @TidusSmith: Enable all the compiler warnings you can; then you *should* get a warning if the compiler finds a return path that doesn't return a value. It's not an error since, in the general case, it can be impossible to identify all possible return paths at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `numbers` constructor in the initializer list of `Class` constructor:

```
Class::Class(std::deque<int>& mydeck):numbers(mydeck) {
}
```

Of course, this is only needed if you want to pass any parameters to the constructor. If you don't need, and if there's constructor that takes no arguments, it will be called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If it's declared as `stack<int> numbers;` then it will be created when the constructor is called:

```
class Class
{
private:
  stack<int> numbers;

public:
  Class() { /* numbers exists here, it's an empty stack */ }
  Class(const stack<int>& n) : numbers(n) { /* numbers contains the copy of n's elements */ }
};
```